# Update multiple records with IF/ELSE IF?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have roughly 100 records that need to be changed in a database, and these need to be updated in rapid succession. They then have to be reverted to their original contents.

Consider the following as my data structure:

`[old value]  [new value]
 |row1   |   |row1   |
 |ark-PAR|   |ark-paw|
 |ark-BAR|   |ark-pag|`

as well as:

`[old value][new value]
 |row2   |  |row2   |
 |vim-PAR|  |vim-paw|
 |vim-BAR|  |vim-pag|`

How would one go about to search in row1 for e.g. ark-PAR, then replace it with ark-paw, as well as search in row2 for vim-PAR and replace it with vim-paw, and then do the same for ark-BAR, vim-BAR, etc?

I am guessing that some form of statement such as (note; incorrect syntax):

```
IF (dbo.table.row1 = 'vim-PAR') 
update dbo.row1 
set row1 = replace(row1, 'ark-PAR', 'ark-paw)
AND set row2 = replace(row2, 'vim-PAR', 'vim-paw'
```

would be the best in order to do so, but how do I do this for several rows and items?

I have seen several resources online discussing nestled replaces, but this does not seem feasible for over 100 records.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using?  "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: My bad -- updated tag to sql-server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
update [table] set [column] = 'ark-paw' where [column] = 'ark-PAR'
update [table] set [column] = 'ark-pag' where [column] = 'ark-BAR'
update [table] set [column] = 'vim-paw' where [column] = 'vim-PAR'
update [table] set [column] = 'vim-pag' where [column] = 'vim-BAR'
```

Note: you have to provide table & column name that you want to update.

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution as it makes fast updates

```
UPDATE dbo.table SET row1 =(
    CASE row1
    WHEN 'ark-PAR' THEN 'ark-paw' 
    WHEN 'vim-PAR' THEN 'vim-paw' WHEN 'ark-BAR' 
    THEN 'ark-pag' 
    WHEN 'vim-BAR' THEN 'vim-pag' END)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution. it resolves your problem. I have tested this query.
[image: see the attchment result]

Comment: its different i use row wise update  see answer carefully

Comment: Apologies, upvoted :) But don't post pictures with code! It's the worst thing you can do.